# MySQL query: Search same column multiple time

Tags: mysql

Table name: products
Column names and data

```
type        item       
------      -------  
Electronic  Mobile
Mobile      Smartphone
Smartphone  Samsung
```

So how the query should be written? I've tried

```
select * from products where (type='Electronic' and item='Mobile') 
    and (type='Smartphone' and item='Samsung')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `AND`, you need `OR`. A record can't be **both** Electronic/Mobile ***and*** Smartphone/Samsung.

Answer (score 1):

In the query you written, parenthesis are useless - they simply do nothing.

Hoever, I think you should use an OR instead:

```
SELECT* FROM products WHERE (type='Electronic' AND item='Mobile') OR (type='Smartphone' AND item='Samsung');
```

But this query will perform poorly on big tables. So, I have 2 suggestions:

1) Replace '*' with the list of columns you really need.

2) Split into 2 queries:

```
SELECT* FROM products WHERE type='Electronic' AND item='Mobile';
SELECT* FROM products WHERE type='Smartphone' AND item='Samsung';
```

...or at least use a `UNION`:

```
(SELECT* FROM products WHERE type='Electronic' AND item='Mobile')
UNION ALL
(SELECT* FROM products WHERE type='Smartphone' AND item='Samsung');
```